# How can we compute $\int^{\infty}_0\sin(x^2)dx$ using Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, improper-integrals

> How can we compute $\int^{\infty}_0\sin(x^2)dx$ using Fourier transform?

I had an idea in my mind. To use the $\text{sinc}$ function and take its inverse Fourier Transform or something like that. I also tried using the inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac1{x^2}$, but I cannot use the fact to this improper integral.

Can someone point me out how can we use the Fourier Transform here?

*Please only use Fourier Transform, nothing else.*

Comment: Oh, you're using Riemann integral then. But no matter what my comment was wrong...

Comment: @Tryss, no problem. (y) But how can I solve it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only a partial answer, but maybe useful. *Assuming* $\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx=\int_0^\infty\cos(x^2)dx$ (which is numerically verified and possibly easy to prove), and employing the Fourier transform
$$
\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}e^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}x\xi}=2\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\infty dx \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}x\xi}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|\xi|}}\ ,
$$
we have easily 
$$
I=\int_0^\infty dx\cos(x^2)=\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\infty dx\ e^{\mathrm{i}x^2}=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\infty dy\ \frac{e^{\mathrm{i}y}}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{1}{4}\hat{f}\left(-\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}\ .
$$

Comment: I didn't understand the last step. Can you explain it please? How you got $-\frac1{2\pi}$ there?

Comment: From the first line, you read $$ \mathrm{Re}\int_0^\infty dx\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}e^{-2\pi\mathrm{i}x\xi}=\frac{1}{2}\hat{f}(\xi)$$. So if you compute $(1/2)\hat{f}(\xi)$ at $\xi=-1/(2\pi)$, you precisely obtain $\mathrm{Re}\int_0^\infty dy \frac{e^{\mathrm{i}y}}{\sqrt{y}}$, which is the integral you need on the second line.

Comment: Can we use the unnormalized sinc function also? Is there a way with that? $\text{sinc}(x^2)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$.

Comment: The equality $\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)dx=\int_0^{\infty}\cos(x^2)dx$ is indeed established. These integrals (with variable upper limit) are the [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), both of which have the limit $\sqrt{\pi/8}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Properties)).

Comment: @Matt. True. But if we assume we know about Fresnel integral (which of course I do), the whole question is pointless. My point is: suppose we *don't* know anything about Fresnel. Is it possible to show [using only algebraic manipulations] that $\int_0^\infty dx\sin(x^2)=\int_0^\infty dx\cos(x^2)$ [no matter what the actual value of the integral is]? If yes, then use my answer from that point onwards.

Comment: @Aditya Agarwal. If you define the Fourier transform of $\mathrm{sinc}(x^2)$ as $$ \hat{g}(\xi)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}e^{-2 \pi\mathrm{i}\xi x}dx$$, then by taking two derivatives w.r.t. $\xi$ you get $$ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial\xi^2}\hat{g}(\xi)=-4\pi^2\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\sin(x^2)e^{-2 \pi\mathrm{i}\xi x}$$. Evaluate at $\xi=0$ and you are done: $$\int_0^\infty dx\sin(x^2)=-\frac{1}{8\pi^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\xi^2}\hat{g}(\xi)\Big|_{\xi\to 0}$$.

Comment: Can you add that to the answer please? It is sublime! Thank you so much!

Comment: But how would we evaluate the last double derivative expression?

Comment: @Aditya: we need to agree on a starting point (we should start from somewhere). Do we agree that we *know* (and take for granted) the analytical expression of $\hat{g}(\xi)$ [Mathematica can compute it easily]? If yes, then Mathematica can also compute its second derivative. If not, then I misunderstood your question.

Comment: So it means we cannot do it without that? (Without Mathematica)

Comment: We cannot do *what* without *what*?

Comment: We cannot compute the double derivative without mathematica?

Comment: Sorry, the point is not about Mathematica. The point is what you are assuming you know before tackling your question. If we assume we know the analytical expression of $\hat{g}(\xi)$ [from Mathematica, from tables, from Wikipedia...], then the result follows by differentiating twice [with Mathematica, with pen and paper, hiring someone to do it for you...]. I assumed you had assumed you knew the analytical expression of $\hat{g}(\xi)$ from the very statement of your question: "To use the sinc function and take its inverse Fourier Transform or something like that".

Comment: Ohk yes, you are right, we know all that before hand only. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I hope the Laplace transform is allowed too, since it is just a "rotated variant" of the Fourier transform. We have:
$$ \mathcal{L}(\sin x) = \frac{1}{1+s^2},\qquad \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi s}}\tag{1}$$
hence:

$$ \begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\,dx &=& \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{(1+s^2)\sqrt{s}}\\&=&\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{1+s^4}\tag{2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and the last integral can be computed in many ways, for instance through the residue theorem and/or through partial fraction decomposition ($1+4s^4 = (1-2s+2s^2)(1+2s+2s^2)$).

That leads to:

> $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sin(x^2)\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{8}} = \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}.}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Oh sorry, Fourier Transform was supposed to solve the problem in 3-4 steps. That is why I am after it. I can do nothing more than an upvote to this. Thanks for helping anyway.